# How to change column's value after record is updated in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I have a table with special columns like **Inserted**(Date), **Updated**(Date), **Version**(Number).

**Inserted** - when the record was created (Sysdate).
**Updated** - the latest record's update (Sysdate).
**Version** - default 1. Must be increased by 1 every time record is updated.

How can I make this work in Oracle Apex if I insert/update data via forms? I do not use those columns in forms, but when I update other columns, I want dates / version to be updated automatically.

Somehow **Inserted** works with dynamic action "Set value on page load", but it didn't work with **Updated**.
I also tried with triggers, but it didn't help as well.

Which way would be best to make it work?

Comment: Database triggers will be fine as long as these columns aren't included on the APEX page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two trigger one for insert and an other for update

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <table_name>_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON <table_name>
   FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
   -- Update create date field to current system date
   :new.<Inserted > := sysdate;
   :new.<Updated> := sysdate; 
   :new.<Version> := 1;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <table_name>_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON <table_name>
   FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   -- Update update date field to current system date
   :new.<Updated> := sysdate;
   :new.<Version> := :old.<Version> + 1;
END;
```